# How can we customize the message that the menu function prints?

Tags: r

I use `menu`function like this :

```
a<-menu(c("Option A","Option B"),title="Choose Option")
if (a==1){
...
}else if (a==2){
...
}
else ...
```

However, when I run it and I enter "3", it prints `Enter an item from the menu, or 0 to exit` rather than my own message that I wrote in the last `else`. Is there a way to get rid of this default message?

Comment: How can we reproduce this issue on our end ?

Comment: The sentence "Enter an item from the menu, or 0 to exit" does seem like a reasonable response, doesn't it? Or try `stop` to customize an error message.

Answer (score 1):

That's not an error, but just a fixed printed text by menu. If you want something else, you'll have to not use menu. Just typing menu will show you the code that produces this, and can be used to write your own function with a different message.

You can also assign any message to the function body:

```
my_menu <- menu

body(my_menu)[[9]][[2]][[4]][[2]][[2]] <- "This is my custom message\n"

my_menu(c("Option A","Option B"),title="Choose Option")
# enter 3
```

> ```
> Selection: 3
> This is my custom message
> ```